# Storage quota for 'Document' exceeded In DocumentDB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

In DocumentDB,while inserting documents using stored procedure i am getting error as **Storage quota for 'Document' exceeded.** my collection has 10000 throughput and 250GB capacity with countryId partition key and document size is 3KB.

stored procedure as follows

```js
function addTempResult(documents) {
        for (var i = 0; i < documents.length; i++) {
            var accepted = collection.createDocument(collection.getSelfLink(), documents[i],
                  function (err, documentCreated, options) {
                      if (err) throw new Error('Error' + err.message);
                      getContext().getResponse().setBody(i);
                      
                  });
            if (!accepted) return;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: What's the max size of a single document you are trying to add?

Comment: Have you tried to just `throw err;` if there has error when creating the document in stored procedure? When did you execute the stored proceduce **Script Explorer** or client library? If the storage limitation of your collection is not reached, you could catch the detailed error message for us to locate this issue.

Comment: when i using to upload json files using DocumentDB Data Migration Tool i am getting same error... but out of 1,00,000 files only uploaded 40,000 files.

Comment: I'm getting the same error writing to DocumentDB using the Java API.  I have an "unlimited" size collection, that starts by default at 10x10Gb partitions.  One of my partitions is full.  My understanding is that DocumentDB should split that partition automatically, but that isn't happening.  I have a ticket open to Microsoft, but they are being less than helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You've exceeded the amount of total storage that has been allocated for that collection.  Partitions currently do not automatically split.  You'll have to call/email into support to get a storage size increase.  Best to do this ahead of time, otherwise you will not be able to take in more writes.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to choose your logical partition to be or more fine grain.
Document DB supports only a maximum of 10 GB per logical partition.

Logical partitions are based on the partition key you chose.
Document DB applies a hash to the logical partition key to determine a physical partition key,  Physical partitions are 10 GB of size.
Multiple logical partitions can end up in the same physical partition and as the data grows Document Db would automatically split the physical partitions until a single logical partition occupies the entire 10 GB ( or 1 physical partition).
Once that is reached you would not be able to store more data for that logical partition.

See this for detailed explaination:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partition-data#partitioning-in-azure-cosmos-db